# htaccess prevent access to .php and allow only with RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file .htaccess with these RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**It's possible to prevent direct access to all these files, but allow access only with RewriteRule**

For example if someone call: "domain.com/**login**" should see the page.

But if someone call "domain.com/**login.php**" should not (in this case should see a 403 or 404 error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an additional rule for blocking direct access to `.php` files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: thx, because i have to prevent access in many many pages, is possibile to have a single rule for each page or a single rule for all php pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line

```
RewriteRule login.php$ 403.php
```

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry this won't work because of Internal Redirection

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule login.php$ 403.php [L]
```

Comment: whit this rule the page "login.php" will be blocked, but the page "login" too :(