# how to secure php files with htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a rest PHP server so most of paths looks like this

```
/test/home.php/product
```

My intention is to secure the api and prevent the access directly to the PHP files.
After some research ,I found someone asking about how to hide PHP extention
and this was his solution :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

so the new route is `/test/product` and it gives the same response as `/test/home.php/product`
but this seems useless because the old url is still working

Can't i prevent the access is the PHP extention appear in the url ?

PS: my question is different from [htaccess prevent access to .php and allow only with RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232693/htaccess-prevent-access-to-php-and-allow-only-with-rewriterule)

since i demand to protect the routes that contains php extention inside them not ends with php

Comment: You should have the files outside of the document root and use a router instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623725

Comment: @neil no this is not the same i have done the change but i want to limit the access for old url /test/home.php/product but keep it working for /test/product

Comment: Ah, the above example only returned forbidden if the URL ends in .php. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232693

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess prevent access to .php and allow only with RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232693/htaccess-prevent-access-to-php-and-allow-only-with-rewriterule)

Comment: i have different routes , stop looking for duplications and answer if you know

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

From: [htaccess prevent access to .php and allow only with RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232693)

Comment: nope i want to limit the access when for the old url but not for the new one

Comment: I've edited the link to an example which forbids access to URLs with .php in them.

Comment: Sure. The critical lines are now displayed above.

Comment: i added that to my .htaccess and it didn't change anything , still the same problem

Comment: change you answer to support url that have php extention within them not only those ends with php

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is at the top of your API files:

```
if(!defined('INSYSTEM')) {
    exit;
}
```

then make a proxy script that you allow access to:

```
define('INSYSTEM', 1);
if($_REQUEST['page'] == 'home') {
    require 'home.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: In this case, isn't it easier just to have them outside of the document root and only have the "proxy" script (which is more like a router, actually) in the document root?

Comment: there could be a server(host) that only gives access to the public folder to upload to

Comment: Most hosts allows you to have files one level up at least. If they don't, then you should change host, in my opinion.

Comment: in this case the proxy will be a php file too it's still the same if i have to call /proxy.php/product

Comment: the code in your api files won't execute; you can add a header("") in them to redirect to index page and then exit